# How to use i2c port based lidar scanner to get laser data to ros?

Tags: ros, laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a garmin lidar lite v3 sensor attached to the i2c port of the beagle bone black that running ros on ubuntu. Is there any implementation on i2c port instead of serial port to get laser data for ros. Because many examples for serial laser data scanners not for i2c interface based lidar scanner .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270293/how-to-use-i2c-port-based-lidar-scanner-to-get-laser-data-to-ros-?/) by [kaviranga](https://answers.ros.org/users/23319/kaviranga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any. The [lidar-lite-ros-scanner-driver](https://github.com/r3n33/lidar-lite-ros-scanner-driver) appears to use an Arduino that performs the i2c interfacing and then data is transmitted to a ROS PC via USB (Serial). There is code for interfacing the sensor via a Pi out there (Python code [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=179248) for instance), so if you want to interface directly, you might have to write some code yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-06**:
I think I'd agree with Stefan: this is not a common thing, as most of the time ROS nodes will not interface with I2C buses directly. If you're lucky the serial port access will be abstracted enough in existing nodes so you can replace it with a (buffered) I2C wrapper class.

**Comment by [kaviranga](https://answers.ros.org/users/23319/kaviranga/) on 2017-12-20**:
@gvdhoorn Finally I found that ! . This is a working example of lidar lite wrapper class for ros laser node . This example for hector-slam and they have included their partial-research paper with this repository.

**Comment by [kaviranga](https://answers.ros.org/users/23319/kaviranga/) on 2017-12-20**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher @gvdhoorn This i2c wrapper written in c language. [hector-slam-wreck](https://github.com/anthonymonori/hector-slam-wreck/tree/master/lidarlite_scan) .